# Heroku app crashing - everything works locally

Tags: heroku

For my app I have my Postgres database deployed to AWS, server (Node and Express) and client (React) separately deployed to Heroku. My client application keeps crashing though and I'm unsure why. Everything works when run locally.

```
2020-05-01T17:18:33.292129+00:00 app[web.1]: > jepurdy@0.1.0 start /app
2020-05-01T17:18:33.292130+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-05-01T17:18:33.292130+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-01T17:18:36.464174+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.97.46/
2020-05-01T17:18:36.464711+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-05-01T17:18:36.464811+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-05-01T17:18:36.464902+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-05-01T17:18:36.465139+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-05-01T17:18:36.465140+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-01T17:18:36.613427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-01T17:18:37.853487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=jepurdy.herokuapp.com request_id=01b14ed3-4b6c-44e1-a2c9-7cfbd728b7ad fwd="75.155.134.45" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-01T17:18:38.248004+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jepurdy.herokuapp.com request_id=a3519a2e-1ef9-49be-baa4-d4ed19f9d833 fwd="75.155.134.45" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here's the package.json for the client:

```
{
  "name": "jepurdy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-spinners-css": "^1.1.7",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the development server on Heroku, but that's probably not your problem. Please [edit] your question and add your `package.json`.

Comment: @Chris Had to remove some of the error message but I've added the package.json

Comment: @Chris Anything in the package.json stand out as needing to be fixed?

Comment: Do you have a back-end service? Normally, React shouldn't be doing anything on the server at runtime. Once it's been built and deployed it just needs to be served as static files.

Comment: I do, but since it's a multiplayer game I have the backend and React communicating via Socket.IO. When React hears certain events it'll change what's rendered.

Comment: Are you trying to run the back-end service on the same Heroku app?

Comment: No, the backend I have deployed as a separate Heroku app.

Comment: Then you might want to consider [a different buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack). Your code just needs to be bundled and served as a static site. I probably can't help much more, as I'm not a React developer.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. Thank you for your help.